# R scripting for hillShade

Tags: raster, r, hillshade

I'm trying to use a csv table with angle and azimuth values to compute a hillshade on the same area at different dates.

I'm using *for* and each date to extract the correct values, but it doesn't seem to be working out. It produces rasters with the exact same hillshade (presumably based on the values from the first line).

```
Date   Angle   Azimuth
Jan01  69.77   225.41
Jan06  70.50   225.56
Jan11  71.32   226.24
```

```
for(d in insol$Date){
hillShade(slope, aspect, angle=insol$Angle, direction=insol$Azimuth, filename=paste(d,".tif"))
}
```

Is there a way to tell R to use the values from each row at a time? The output states (sorry, in Portuguese):

```
> warnings()
Mensagens de aviso:
1: In cos(slp) * cos(zenith) :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
2: In sin(slp) * sin(zenith) :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
3: In cos(slp) * cos(zenith) :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
4: In sin(slp) * sin(zenith) :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over rows of the data frame and extract the `i`-th element from the vector:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(nsol)){
  d = nsol$Date[i]
  hillshade(..., nsol$Aspect[i], nsol$Azimuth[i],...etc...)
}
```